# Tried tinkering with throttling in React Native simulators in order to test caching, but to no avail

Tags: react-native, debugging, caching, throttling, internet-connection

[image]

I tried the Open JS Debugger button in the image above and changing the internet connection to slow connection and even to offline just like the image below.

[image]

But, when I check the network preview, the API can still be called. What's wrong with the dubugger?[image]

I am thinking if I need to use React Native Remote Debugger js, but I don't think that's what I need with the embedded debugger in my simulators. I will appreciate any helpful advice and guidance! Thanks a million!